# Swift - how to create custom operators to use in other modules?

Tags: swift, operators

I created a sample project and a framework next to it. The framework is called "SampleFramework". Then I created a custom operator in SampleFramework. Here is what it looks like:

```
infix operator >>= {associativity left}
public func >>=<A, B>(a: A?, f: A -> B?) -> B? {
    if let a = a { return f(a) }
    else { return .None }
}
```

Then I wanted to use it my main application. I imported the `SampleFramework` to my source file and then I wrote this code to test it:

```
NSURL(string: "www.google.com") >>= { println("\($0)") }
```

It didn't compile. Here is Xcode's error message:

> Ambiguous operator declarations found for operator. Operator is not a
>   known binary operator

Comment: Is it declared at top-level scope?

Comment: Yes It is declared in top level scope. In framework there is only one swift source file. Inside the file there is only the operator declaration.

Comment: I don't see a `precedence` specification for your operator — maybe that has something to do with it?

Comment: No. If I remove the operator declaration code and rewrite it in main project it works

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I can confirm that that what you are seeing is what really happens. I just tried it myself and I've seen the same result.

My opinion is that `>>=` is somehow conflicting with some other operator (probably the bite shift operator: `>>`) or is being declared somewhere else too (you can see why I think that [here](http://www.openradar.me/22676864)). I did **successfully** declared custom operators in a framework and used those in the main app code before (you can see that [here](https://github.com/nakkoservices/nkjson/blob/master/NKJSON/NKJSON.swift) for example).

What I would suggest is rename your custom operator to something else. When I did that (renamed the custom operator to `>>>=`) the compiler stopped complaining and my app compiled just fine.

### Later edit

Ok. So this might help a bit more. Basically when an operator is already declared and you want to add *extra* functionality to that operator (for example doing things like `3 * "Hello"` like [Johan Kool](https://stackoverflow.com/users/60488/johan-kool) said he wanted to) all you have to do is **overload** that operator's method.

Basically, in your specific case I am now 100% that `>>=` is an already declared operator and you can go ahead and just add these lines in your framework:

```
public func >>=<A, B>(a: A?, f: A -> B?) -> B? {
    if let a = a { return f(a) }
    else { return .None }
}
```

This will make your operator work. **BUT** it will inherit the precedence and associativity of the original operator thus giving you less control over how it's supposed to behave.

Comment: It seems that you came to the same conclusion than me (finally).

Comment: This isn't quite true as I just came up with some random operator that there is no way it would be used anywhere else, and I still get the same thing so it's not redeclaring an existing operator. Try it yourself.  Create a crazy-long operator.

Answer (score 10):

I figured it out. I think declaration of operator (`infix operator >>= {associativity left}`) is module specific. You can't apply access control to it. But the operator function can be accessed in other modules. So in order to make this work I had to copy operator declaration and paste it to main project.

Comment: But be aware, because if you extend an existing operator like I did, it'll bite. I tried to use `*` to be able to say `3 * "Hello"`, but then the normal multiplication operations stopped working with that same "Ambiguous operator declarations found for operator. Operator is not a known binary operator" message.

Comment: The way to do it is to declare the operator ONLY in your app and declare the function for that operator as a public function in your framework. If you write the operator declaration in both your framework and your app you will get an ambiguous operator error

Comment: I'd regard this as a bug in Swift. What for is a framework if not to offer things like that out-of-the-box? I have a framework with tons of vector operations declared. Now one needs to add a piece of code to his own code. This is silly to be polite. Btw: Using XCode8/Swift3 meanwhile

Comment: This is not true. See my answer.

Comment: Inspecting my .swiftinterface file, it would appear that custom operators are being added to the public API of modules, regardless of the access control of the operator's function. Not sure why this is the case to me, seems like an odd design decision (unless it's a bug...)

Answer (score 4):

It seems to be sufficient to just add the

```
infix operator + : Additive
```

in each source where you want to apply your framework-defined operator, assuming that your framework has some

```
public func + (lhs: ...
```

declared.

Anyhow, it's nasty to have the need for adding this if you use a framework and I'd like to see some way to have some global approach where importing a framework also makes available the operators automatically.

**Edit** After fiddling around for hours, the problem went away. I have not figured out what's the cause. I had lots of `infix` declarations in my basic framework (for historic reason). Once I got rid of them, everything went to normal. So now that I have only `infix` for the new operators, it's fine. But obviously re-declaring existing ones (like `*`, `+`, etc.) Swift seems to get hick-ups.